# How do I find the fourier series of $\sin^3x$ using $\cos$ and $\sin$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I want to express $$f(x) = \sin^3x$$ in terms of its fourier series using the fourier series of $sin2x$ and $cos^2 x$ between the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ for a period of $2\pi$. Respectively here is what I found:

$$\sin2x = \sum^{\infty}_1b_n \sin(nx)$$

$$\cos^2x = \frac{a_0}{2} +  \sum^{\infty}_1a_n cos(nx)$$

But from what I have searched online, $sin^3x$ requires an expression in terms of $sin3x$, so I'm unable to use this fact with my requirements of $cosx$ and sin$2x$

Comment: 1. It should be Fourier, with a capital letter. 2. $\sin^3 x$ is an odd function, hence its Fourier series only has sine terms 3. $$\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^3 = \ldots = \frac{3}{4}\sin(x)-\frac{1}{4}\sin(3x).$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is $\sin^3 x=\frac{3}{4}\sin x - \frac{1}{4}\sin 3x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97654/is-sin3-x-frac34-sin-x-frac14-sin-3x)